# Why is not checking and unchecking the checkboxes?

Tags: jquery

I have the following query code:

```
function selectTag(id) {
    var input = 'input#tag_' + id;
    var span = '#span_' + id;

    if ($(input).is(':checked') && $(span).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(span).removeClass('selected');
        $(input).prop('checked', false);
    }
    else {
        $(span).addClass('selected');
        $(input).prop('checked', true);
    }
}
```

and the last part of the conditional is not executing. The check boxes are not being checked or unchecked.

Here is the html.

```
<?php foreach ($this->tags as $uri=>$tag){?>
     <input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" style="display: none;" value="<?php echo $uri;?>" id="tag_<?php echo $uri;?>" <?php echo isset($args['tags']) && in_array($uri, $args['tags'])?'checked="checked"':'';?> />
     <span onclick="selectTag(<?php echo $uri;?>)" id="span_<?php echo $uri;?>" for="create_<?php echo $uri;?>" class="tag <?php echo isset($args['tags']) && in_array($uri, $args['tags'])?'selected':'';?>"><?php echo str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $tag);?></span>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Please share your HTML.

Comment: Are you using the correct version of jQuery (1.6+)?

Comment: @AndrewArnold I am using JQuery 1.10

Comment: Please share the HTML as rendered by your browser. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints in the JS? Is that function ever actually called?

Comment: yes I set flags to see if its called and to see if its going inside the conditional. And it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this: **[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j4e8g/1/)**

- There is no need to use `onClick` attribute when you are using jQuery. You can do it by [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event instead. So there is no need to pass element id to the function. `$(this)` holds the element object and you can access the id attribute by `attr('id')`.

**jQuery**

```
$('span').click(function(){
    var id =  $(this).attr('id');
    var input = $('input#tag_' + id);
    var span = $(this);
    if (input.is(':checked') && span.hasClass('selected')) {
        span.removeClass('selected');
        input.prop('checked', false);
    }
    else {
       span.addClass('selected');
        input.prop('checked', true);
    } 
});
```

**html**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]"  value="" id="tag_1" />
<span id="1" for="" class="tag selected">siamak 1</span>

<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="" id="tag_2" />
<span id="2" for="" class="tag selected">siamak 12</span>


<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="" id="tag_3" />
<span id="3" for="" class="tag selected">siamak 3</span>
```

---

Also you can get it done another way without id attribute: **[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j4e8g/4/)**

**jQuery**

```
$('span').click(function(){
    var span = $(this);
    var input = $(this).prev();
    if (input.is(':checked') && span.hasClass('selected')) {
        span.removeClass('selected');
        input.prop('checked', false);
    } else {
       span.addClass('selected');
        input.prop('checked', true);
    } 
});
```

**html**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]"  value=""  />
<span  for="" class="tag selected">siamak 1</span>

<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="" />
<span  for="" class="tag selected">siamak 2</span>


<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="" />
<span  for="" class="tag selected">siamak 3</span>
```